# How to get raspberry pi Ip with only Ethernet cable and my window laptop. No internet connection?

Tags: networking, ethernet, remote, desktop

I have raspberry pi 4. I want to get the private Ip of raspberry pi using an ethernet cable and connecting to my laptop which has windows 10 OS but both the pi and laptop are **not connected** to internet. I want to get Ip when the pi and my laptop are connected together via ethernet cable  and without internet.

after getting Ip I will be able to run remote desktop client.

I tried using ipconfig below is the pic

[image]

but the given Ip didn't work on mobaxterm SSH client.

So, how to get the private Ip which will work in that SSH client.

Comment: This question has been asked & answered at various times. Have you tried searching for an answer? Maybe try [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=direct+ethernetconnection+from+PC+to+raspberry+pi&ia=web)? ALSO: DO NOT post screen shots of your terminal - it's one of the surest ways to get your question ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the IP address of Raspberry Pi when it's connected to your router via Ethernet? If so, log onto your router and look for your Raspberry Pi (typically the hostname is something like raspberrypi).

Answer (score 1):

The Pi will get an IP address in at least two possible ways:
1) By using DHCP communication with a DHCP server (usually on the closest router).
2) By static configuration in the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf

In either case, the pi IP address can be found by the ifconfig command on the pi. Look specifically for the eth0 area in the output

The Pi will generally communicate with your laptop by having them both connected to an ethernet switch. If it is only a switch and not a router (or if there is no router also connected to the switch), there may not be anything to respond to a DHCP request, but you can still configure static IP addresses and get the pi and the laptop to communicate.

If the pi and the laptop are directly connected by a dedicated ethernet cable (and not to any switch), it used to require a crossover cable (not sure if it still does) and would have to use static IPs.

Comment: Oh no, please don't confuse someone with telling something about an crossover cable. This is autodetected since years, no matter what cable do you use.